# Access item in observable collection on item selected

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, treeview, observablecollection

I have a WPF TreeView populated by an observable collection using a hiarchialdatabinding
I need to access the item in my observable collection or the database that was used to populate it.
An example use case is that the user right clicks a treeview item to add a subgroup. I obviously need to access its parent to add the child.
Any suggestions? Im so lost..

I cant just edit the treeview item itself cause then the changes wont reflect back to my database

Database Code:

```
[Serializable]
public class LoginGroup
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public List<Login> LoginItems = new List<Login>();
    public List<LoginGroup> Children { get; set; }
}

public static ObservableCollection<LoginGroup> _GroupCollection = new  ObservableCollection<LoginGroup>();

public ObservableCollection<LoginGroup> GroupCollection
{
    get { return _GroupCollection; }
}
```

TreeView:

```
<TreeView x:Name="groupView" Width="211" TreeViewItem.Selected="OnTreeItemSelected" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Height="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding GroupCollection}" >
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just cast the `SelectedItem` to `LoginGroup`:

```
LoginGroup selectedGroup = (LoginGroup)groupView.SelectedItem;
```

Comment: This much I know, thats not my issue. See the last line. I cant just edit the treeview item itself cause then the changes wont reflect back to my database

Comment: @Lexi, I'm not suggesting that you edit the TreeView itself; perform whatever changes you need on `selectedGroup`, then save that to the database... Which part are you having trouble with exactly?

Comment: Well, thats my problem.. Im not sure how I would go about finding my way to that item in the database, say its a child of a child of a child of a child etc.. How would I go about finding the same position in the database? Ive tried experimenting with the use of an unique identifier, but no luck

Answer (score 0):

You should use TreeView's ItemContainer style.
Here's sample TreeNode view model:

```
public class TreeNode : ViewModel
{
    public TreeNode()
    {
        this.children = new ObservableCollection<TreeNode>();

        // the magic goes here
        this.addChildCommand = new RelayCommand(obj => AddNewChild());
    }

    private void AddNewChild()
    {
        // create new child instance
        var child = new TreeNode 
        { 
            Name = "This is a new child node.",
            IsSelected = true // new child should be selected
        };

        // add it to collection
        children.Add(child);

        // expand this node, we want to look at the new child node
        IsExpanded = true;
    }

    public String Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            if (name != value)
            {
                name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }
    private String name;

    public Boolean IsSelected
    {
        get { return isSelected; }
        set
        {
            if (isSelected != value)
            {
                isSelected = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
            }
        }
    }
    private Boolean isSelected;

    public Boolean IsExpanded
    {
        get { return isExpanded; }
        set
        {
            if (isExpanded != value)
            {
                isExpanded = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsExpanded");
            }
        }
    }
    private Boolean isExpanded;

    public ObservableCollection<TreeNode> Children
    {
        get { return children; } 
    }
    private ObservableCollection<TreeNode> children;

    public ICommand AddChildCommand
    {
        get { return addChildCommand; }
    }
    private RelayCommand addChildCommand;
}
```

Some comments:

- ViewModel is any base implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged
  interface.
- RelayCommand (a.k.a. DelegateCommand) is ICommand implementation for use in MVVM approach.

Here's the view:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <!-- Let's glue our view models with the view! -->
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ContextMenu>
                            <!-- Here's menu item, which is responsible for adding new child node -->
                            <MenuItem Header="Add child..." Command="{Binding AddChildCommand}" />
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
</Window>
```

... and sample data context initialization:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ObservableCollection<TreeNode>
        {
            new TreeNode { Name = "Root", IsSelected = true }
        };
    }
```

Hope this helps.

**Upd**.
Of course, you have to expose child nodes as the ObservableCollection too. Otherwise, changes made to nodes collection won't be reflected.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance. But Im not entirely sure how I would use something like this to i.e add a child to when a click in a context menu for the selected item has been done.

Comment: @Lexi, you can define context menu in ItemContainerStyle too. Add item to menu a bind the command of item to any ICommand property of your view model. Then, handle this command (write code to add child items).

Comment: Would this view model be serializable or would I need to find a way to clone the contents over to my db file?

Comment: @Lexi: conceptually, view models shouldn't support any serialization way, this is what **model** is responsible for. This is because view model can contains data or functional, which is needed for GUI interaction, but is useless for storage (look at AddChildCommand, for example). But, if in your application model and view model are identical for simplicity, you may add any serialization attributes directly into view model's code.

Comment: I see, doesn't seem wise to serialize it then. Any way to copy data to and from a serializable class such as the login group I have in my initial post for storage, containing all child's and such?

Answer (score 0):

You can't reflect back changed of your properties because they don't have way to "notice" back that they are edited. You need inherit `LoginGroup` from `DependencyObject` or implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`

Comment: So if I implement INotifyPropertyChanged and change the data via  groupView.SelectedItem, it should automatically be reflected back?

Comment: If you mean change property `Name` - yes.

Comment: What if I need to add items to the list children? Will that be reflected as well